# laravel form submit uses wrong controller method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Im trying to use a form to submit reviews for products but I believe the submit button uses the incorrect controller store method. I have a controller for products and one for reviews. The products store works correctly and I can see the database being populated once submitted however when I go to submit a review for a product it will throw the custom error messages from the product store form. If I change the reviews form::open to the products form::open it will throw an error: The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.

Products form (works properly)

```
        {!! Form::open(['action' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

        ... labels and text ...

        {{ Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Reviews form

```
                <div>
                    <p>Write a review</p>
                    <!-- submit review form -->
                    {!! Form::open(['reviews' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ReviewsController@store']) !!}
                    <div class="form-group">

                        {{ Form::textarea('description', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Write your message']) }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('rating', 'Rating') }}
                        {{ Form::select('rating', ['1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' => '5'], '1') }}
                    </div>

                    {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') }}
                    {{ Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}

                </div>
```

ReviewsController store

```
    public function store(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['description' => 'nullable',
  'rating' => 'nullable',
        ]);

        $review =  new Review;

        $review->rating = $request->input('rating');
        $review->reviewerid = auth()->user()->id;
        $review->productid = $id;
        $review->description = $request->input('description');

        $review->save();

        return redirect('/products/$id')->with('success', 'Review submitted');
    }
```

Web.php file

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@abouts');
Route::get('/cart', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@cart');
Route::get('/checkout', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@checkout');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@services');
Route::get('/categories/{Category}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@category');
Route::resource('reviews', 'App\Http\Controllers\ReviewsController');
Route::resource('products', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController');
Auth::routes();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of this line:

```
Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')
```

You're telling laravel to use put method. Delete it and it will work fine.

For your form action, I think you have type in this line:

```
{!! Form::open(['reviews' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ReviewsController@store']) !!}
```

Change it to :

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ReviewsController@store']) !!}
```

Comment: thanks it seems i made a little bit of progress. i had to run the "php artisan route:clear" command for it to show up